# PyCharm can't install packages: "VC 6.0 is not supported by this module"

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I'm trying to configure an interpreter and install packages, but I get this error. I have previously installed and used Pycharm Community without any problems.

I tried to install via cmd and updated pip to the latest version. I tried to used the base interpreter and also create a new one.

Do anyone now an answer to this?

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.5.2.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [71 lines of output]
  Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
    Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.32
    Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.21.6
    Using cached numpy-1.21.6.zip (10.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
    Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
  
    [40 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        backend = _build_backend()
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
        obj = import_module(mod_path)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ws0et5_\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ws0et5_\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
        patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ws0et5_\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
        patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ws0et5_\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
        mod = import_module(mod_name)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\Wiltsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ws0et5_\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
    [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Your actual error was completely buried in all that, so I put it in the title for you. You didn't indicate that you've done any specific research whatsoever on what causes the `VC 6.0 is not supported by this module` error. The solutions you've tried so far don't appear to be along the lines of what other people were suggested to do once they got that error.

Comment: How are you installing the packages? `pandas` and most of its dependencies, including `numpy`, are available as wheels for Python 3.10 and don't need to be compiled. Something strange is going on here...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [msys2/mingw64: pip: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166914/msys2-mingw64-pip-vc-6-0-is-not-supported-by-this-module)