# distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module

Tags: python, msys2, msvc12

I tried to install a package "nbtlib" in Windows 10 (mingw64) and got this error:

```
Collecting nbtlib
  Using cached nbtlib-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)        
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import      
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked    
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:/Users/Rudradev Arya/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-om7n17__/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:/Users/Rudradev Arya/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-om7n17__/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:/Users/Rudradev Arya/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-om7n17__/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
        File "C:/Users/Rudradev Arya/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-om7n17__/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)        
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import      
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked    
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:/Users/Rudradev Arya/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-om7n17__/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

what can i do to fix this?
my wheel, pip, setuptools,msys,python are all up to date

i tried looking up for answers but none of them seem to help me or they were not for windows
any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't know why, but this works for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166914/msys2-mingw64-pip-vc-6-0-is-not-supported-by-this-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [msys2/mingw64: pip: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166914/msys2-mingw64-pip-vc-6-0-is-not-supported-by-this-module)