# How to use MinGW-w64 instead of Microsoft Visual C++ when pip install pytest-playwright

Tags: python, pip, mingw

I would like to use Playwright for Python in a non-privileged environment.

After running `pip install pytest-playwright` in the embedded python environment, I get the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [90 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\leakcheck.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_contextvars.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_cpp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_extension_interface.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_gc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator_nested.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_greenlet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_greenlet_trash.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_leaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_stack_saved.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_throw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_tracing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_weakref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      running egg_info
      writing src\greenlet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\greenlet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\greenlet.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\greenlet.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'benchmarks\*.json'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_allocator.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_compiler_compat.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_cpython_compat.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_exceptions.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_greenlet.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_internal.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_refs.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_slp_switch.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_thread_state.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_thread_state_dict_cleanup.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_thread_support.hpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\slp_platformselect.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\platform\setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_alpha_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_amd64_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_ios.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm64_masm.asm -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm64_masm.obj -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm64_msvc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_csky_gcc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_mips_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_aix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_linux.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_ppc_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_riscv_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_s390_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x32_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_masm.asm -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_masm.obj -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x64_msvc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x86_msvc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_x86_unix.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\tests\_test_extension.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\greenlet\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for greenlet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The error message says "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.", but I am forbidden to install Microsoft Visual C++.

Is it possible to install pytest-playwright using MinGW-w64 instead of Microsoft Visual C++?

I have tried the following three different methods and could not install `pytest-playwright` successfully.

- Add PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg and run `pip install pytest-playwright`.

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler=mingw32
```

- Install with a .zip file downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/releases/tag/v0.4.3) using option `--global-option` and `--compiler`.

```
> pip install --global-option build_ext --global-option --compiler=mingw32 playwright-pytest-0.4.3.zip
```

- Install with .whl files

```
> pip install greenlet-3.0.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
> pip install pytest_playwright-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

My environment is as follows:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2 64-bit
- Python: 3.12.0 embeddable package (64-bit)
- pip: 23.2.1 (installed using [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py))
- MinGW-w64: 13.2.0 built by MinGW-Builds project (`x86_64-13.2.0-release-posix-seh-ucrt-rt_v11-rev0.7z`)

Comment: I think you need mingw-patched `setuptools`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554854/7976758

Comment: @phd Thank you for your comment. I appreciate your suggestion to use MSYS2. However, I am not allowed to use MSYS2 in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by downgrading Python from version 3.12.0 to version 3.11.6.

Thanks to everyone who commented on my question.
I will mark this question as resolved.