# cant install certain packages on python (pandas, lxml)

Tags: python, pandas, pip, package, lxml

There have been similar questions, but none of them had the same exact problem as I have, I have no clue what to do to fix this issue

When I tried installing lxml and pandas there were errors, but for example json installed with no issue

the error message when installing pandas:
(im sorry if this is a stupid question)

```
`Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [47 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            backend = _build_backend()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
            obj = import_module(mod_path)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 944, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\bepsi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kxqfkbwe\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
            monkey.patch_all()
          File "C:\Users\bepsi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kxqfkbwe\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
            patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
          File "C:\Users\bepsi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kxqfkbwe\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compile
r
            patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\bepsi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kxqfkbwe\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
            mod = import_module(mod_name)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 944, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\bepsi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kxqfkbwe\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>        
            raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
        distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
        [end of output]`
```

I tried updating python, but the error message pretty much didnt change
I tried switching from vscode to pycharm, but it did nothing too

Comment: Apparent duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166914/msys2-mingw64-pip-vc-6-0-is-not-supported-by-this-module

Comment: unfortunately the duplicate question didnt answer my problem, i have no clue how to work it out however i only needed to do one assignment using pandas and i used jupyterhub to do it

Comment: You might want to update your MSVC compiler to a newer version.

Comment: `json` is a built in module, so you should not be installing this.

Comment: The error doesn't come from VSCode or Pycharm; it comes from `pip` which tries to compile the module you are trying to install, but you don't have the necessary tools. Apparently MSYS2 makes this much harder than it needs to be; my recommendation is always to get rid of Windows entirely as soon as you can.